# how to check if there are same consecutive elements in a string or html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this string

```
<div id="ch">abcdefg<img /><img />hij</div>
<div id="ad">abc<img />defg<img />hij</div>

strHtml = $('div#ch').html();
strHtmlFalse = $('div#ad').html();
```

Now is there a possible way to check if two 'img' elements are found and if they are consecutive siblings.

```
chConImg = checkConsecutiveImg(strHtml) //true
chConImgFalse = checkConsecutiveImg(strHtmlFalse) //false


checkConsecutiveImg(str){
    if(consecutive img elements are found)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes there is. A good starting point is often a web search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654091/javascript-function-to-automatically-count-consecutive-letters-in-a-string - if you fail then you'll have code to post in here and ask for help as unfortunately SO is not a place to request code but to ask for help with existing code. So if you don't try anything your chance of getting what you want are limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vanilla Javascript Approach**

```js
function checkConsecutiveImage(str) {
  const parent = document.querySelector(str);
  const children = parent.children;
  const image = Array.from(children).find(elem => elem.tagName === 'IMG');
  
  return image.nextSibling.nodeType === 1 && image.nextElementSibling.tagName === 'IMG'
}

console.log(`Consecutive images in #ch: ${checkConsecutiveImage('#ch')}`);

console.log(`Consecutive images in #ad: ${checkConsecutiveImage('#ad')}`);
```

```html
<div id="ch">abcdefg<img /><img />hij</div>
<div id="ad">abc<img />defg<img />hij</div>
```

**jQuery Approach**

```js
$(function() {
  function checkConsecutiveImg(str) {
    const $img = $(str).find('img');
    
    return $img[0].nextSibling.nodeType === 1 && $img.next().is('img');
  }

  console.log(`Consecutive images in #ch: ${checkConsecutiveImg('#ch')}`);

  console.log(`Consecutive images in #ad: ${checkConsecutiveImg('#ad')}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ch">abcdefg<img /><img />hij</div>
<div id="ad">abc<img />defg<img />hij</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the functions [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/).

```js
function checkConsecutiveImg(parent) {
    const children = parent.contents(); // e.g. ["abcdefg", <img>, <img>, "hij"]
    let containsConsecutives = false;
        
    children.each((index, currentElement) => {
        if ($(currentElement).is('img') && $(children[index - 1]).is('img')) {
            containsConsecutives = true;
        }
    })    
      
    return containsConsecutives;
}

console.log(checkConsecutiveImg($('div#ch')))
console.log(checkConsecutiveImg($('div#ad')))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ch">abcdefg<img /><img />hij</div>
<div id="ad">abc<img />defg<img />hij</div>
```